# SQL Server : change date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to change the date format from 'yyyy-mm-dd' to 'dd.mm.yyyy'.

I have data in my table like this `'2018-08-08'`, I need convert it to `'08.08.2018'`.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE daily_tasks 
SET date = REPLACE(date, date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), daily_tasks.date, 102)) 
WHERE 1;
```

But, it doesn't work.

Comment: You should store dates as `date`, which do not have a format. A format is applied when the value is shown, but internally it has no format. **Never** store dates a varchar's.

Comment: @ClothessSale . . . I changed the tag to sql-server based on the syntax.  Please tag your questions with the software you are really using.

Comment: What is the type of the column `date` in `daily_tasks`? Most answers are assuming it's `DATE` or `DATETIME` or suchlike, but if it's already `VARCHAR`, this statement will run without error (and without doing anything useful). If it *is* `VARCHAR`, then per the others, this is a bad type to use, but it would be even *worse* to change the format from ISO to `dd.mm.yyyy` *in the table*. That's a case where you can definitely get what you want, but you shouldn't be wanting it.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should be storing your dates as bona-fide date columns, *not* as text.  That being said, the date text `'2018-08-08'` is in fact in an ISO format, and would still allow you to do things like sort and compare against other date literals, so it is not so bad.

But converting this text to a `'08.08.2018'` format is the wrong thing to do.  If a anything, you might want to consider adding a new date column `new_date` to store this date information.  Do that, and then populate it with:

```
UPDATE daily_tasks
SET new_date = TRY_CONVERT(datetime, date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Store your date as DATE datatype and when you read data from database use

```
    DECLARE @myDate DATE = '2018-08-08'
SELECT FORMAT(@myDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy')
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @myDate, 104)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks like `SQL Sever`, so i would do :

```
UPDATE daily_tasks 
     SET Col = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), daily_tasks.date, 103), '/', '.')
WHERE . . . ;
```

However, i would not recommend to do this, just use `CONVERT()` with `SELECT` statement  whenever necessary :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), daily_tasks.date, 103), '/', '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the database, dates are stored in an *internal* format.  This is the correct way to store dates.  **Do not store dates as strings.**

You can specify the format when you query:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), daily_tasks.date, 102)
```

Or, you can even add a computed column to provide this information:

```
alter table daily_tasks
    add date_display as ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), daily_tasks.date, 102) ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `date` column to a varchar to store the date in your specified format. However I strongly recommend against this. You should leave it stored as a date.

If you want to do a `SELECT` to get the data out then you can convert it to your specified format like this:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, daily_tasks.date, 4)
```